# How to clear cache of Android's built-in podcast player?

Tags: google, cache

In 2016, Google launched a secret unnamed podcast player. If you search for a podcast, a special player app will appear. This app lets you:

- play podcasts in the background
- with the phone locked
- remembers where you are
- offers to add a link to your home screen

The problem i'm having today is that it's not letting me scroll back to older episodes of the podcast i've been listening to. And any attempts to go back to the web-site causes the *"secret"* player to appear, where it again only lets me see the last few episodes.

I want to clear the cache for this app, so that it doesn't think i've seen it before.

The only problem is that this secret unnamed podcast player doesn't have a name; i don't know what **App** to clear the cache for.

## Bonus Reading

- Media.info: [Google launches podcast player for Android](https://media.info/radio/news/google-launches-podcast-player-for-android)
- Google Developer Docs: [Podcasts](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/podcasts)
- Google Blog: [Listen to podcasts in the Google App on Android](https://www.blog.google/products/search/listen-to-podcasts-in-google-app-on/)
- YouTube: [Android's New Secret Built In Podcast Player? Here's how to use it!](https://youtu.be/vTn4atDUp0g)

Comment: Maybe clearing the cache for Google search app does the trick? Since it seems to be contained in that app. Of course, side effect of losing other data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Apps -> Search 'Google PodCast' -> Storage -> Remove data / cache
(I have Android version 9)